# Selenium Send Enter Key returning error "Object required"

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, sendkeys

Automating filling in online form in Edge using Selenium within VBA but I am receiving an error message when trying to use the SendKeys for Enter.  Note, there is not submit button, Enter is required.

```
Sub Login()
    'Open online trading platform
    Dim obj As New WebDriver
    obj.Start "edge", ""
    obj.Get "https://standard.tradezeroweb.us/"
    obj.Wait 1000
    obj.Window.Maximize
    obj.FindElementById("trading-order-input-symbol").Clear
    obj.FindElementById("trading-order-input-symbol").SendKeys ("AAPL")
    obj.FindElementById("trading-order-input-symbol").SendKeys (Keys.Enter) 'This is where the code fails
End Sub
```

`Sendkeys (Keys.Enter)` returns:

> Run-time error '424':
> Object required

Using `obj.FindElementById("trading-order-input-symbol").SendKeys ("AAPL").submit` returns:

> Run-time error '7': NoSuchElementError

Using `obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=trading-order-input-symbol]").SendKeys (obj.Key.Enter)` returns:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Looking for some assistance and what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "trading-order-input-symbol" element exists then the problem with `obj.FindElementById("trading-order-input-symbol").SendKeys (Keys.Enter)` (that results in the error 424) is that `Keys` does not exist by default ... it must be declared.

So, before that line, add a line `Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys`.

For info, based on the error you are having, I would guess you do not have `Option Explicit` at the top of your Module. This is 'hiding' the problem ... you should always use `Option Explicit`. If you add this (without adding the `Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys` line) and compile your project, the VBE will tell you that 'Keys' is not defined - giving you a clue as to what the problem was.

Comment: Yep, that was it, just needed to declare Keys.  Thank you.  Also added Option Explicit.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped you then please click on the tick / check mark so that the focus remains on the still-unanswered questions.